# split HashMap into equal chunks

Tags: rust

What's the best way to split a `HashMap` into equal chunks? For instance, this is how I split a `Vec<String>`:

```
extern crate num_cpus;

fn main() {

    let cpu_count = num_cpus::get();

    let list: Vec<String> = vec!["one".into(), "two".into(), "three".into(), "four".into(), "five".into(), "six".into(), "seven".into(), "eight".into(), "nine".into(), "ten".into()];

    let chunk_len = (list.len() / cpu_count) as usize + 1;
    let mut chunks = Vec::new();
    for chunk in list.chunks(chunk_len) {
        chunks.push(chunk.to_owned());
    }

    for chunk in chunks {
        println!("{:?}", chunk);
    }

}
```

produces output

```
["one", "two"]
["three", "four"]
["five", "six"]
["seven", "eight"]
["nine", "ten"]
```

How would I do the same with `HashMap<String, String>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes any sense to "chunk" a `HashMap` directly.  In any case, the solution is obvious: *don't*.  You can chunk a `Vec` (actually any array slice), so just use that!  After all, a `HashMap` is logically just an unordered sequence of `(Key, Value)` pairs.

```rust
fn chunk_vec() {
    let cpu_count = 6 /*num_cpus::get()*/;

    let list: Vec<String> = [
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
        "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    ].iter().map(|&s| s.into()).collect();

    let chunk_len = (list.len() / cpu_count) as usize + 1;
    let chunks: Vec<Vec<_>> = list.chunks(chunk_len)
        .map(|c| c.iter().collect())
        .collect();
    for chunk in chunks {
        println!("{:?}", chunk);
    }
}

fn chunk_hash() {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    let cpu_count = 6 /*num_cpus::get()*/;

    let hash: HashMap<String, i32> = [
        ("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3), ("four", 4), ("five", 5),
        ("six", 6), ("seven", 7), ("eight", 8), ("nine", 9), ("ten", 10)
    ].iter().map(|&(k, v)| (k.into(), v)).collect();

    let list: Vec<_> = hash.into_iter().collect();

    let chunk_len = (list.len() / cpu_count) as usize + 1;
    let chunks: Vec<HashMap<_, _>> = list.chunks(chunk_len)
        .map(|c| c.iter().cloned().collect())
        .collect();
    for chunk in chunks {
        println!("{:?}", chunk);
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of fiddling with your example code a little to highlight the similarities (and differences) between the two functions.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious about one thing though, why did you use `hash.into_iter()` instead of `hash.iter()`. I was just trying to multithread my actual situation and the compiler was killing me with `does not live long enough` until I changed `iter()` into `into_iter()`.

Comment: @Caballero: `into_iter()` consumes the subject, taking ownership of its contents.  `iter()` just *borrows* the subject and its contents.  The more immediate reason is that `iter()` produces a sequence of `&(String, i32)`s, whilst `into_iter()` produces a sequence of `(String, i32)`s; note the lack of a borrow!  That reduces the levels of indirection and cloning that I might have to do.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't care about the order of the elements you take out of the `HashMap`, you can convert your `HashMap<String, String>` into a `Vec<(String, String)>` by calling `your_map.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>()`

Then you can use the same algorithm you used to convert your `Vec<String>`

---

To be able to compete with @DK.'s elaborate answer I decided to create a generic version of your chunking algorithm:

```
fn chunk<T, U>(data: U) -> Vec<U>
    where U: IntoIterator<Item=T>,
    U: FromIterator<T>,
    <U as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: ExactSizeIterator
{
    let cpu_count = 6 /*num_cpus::get()*/;

    let mut iter = data.into_iter();
    let iter = iter.by_ref();

    let chunk_len = (iter.len() / cpu_count) as usize + 1;

    let mut chunks = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..cpu_count {
        chunks.push(iter.take(chunk_len).collect())
    }
    chunks
}
```

Try it out in the [PlayPen](http://is.gd/4NPszY)

Comment: *Six seconds*.  Still, mine is longer.  :P

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing